# Ao retornar erro de validação no formulário, objeto fica com os valor digitados

Tags: jsf, primefaces, java-ee

Na tela tenho uma datatable que preencho com uma lista de objetos. Usando f:setPropertyActionListener eu seto um objeto da lista para um objeto auxiliar e mostro ele em um dialog. No método salvar eu falo algumas validações, quando retorna um erro, o objeto da lista fica com os valores que digitei no objeto auxiliar (os dois possuem a mesma referencia).

Botão onde seto o valor no objeto auxiliar:

```
<p:commandButton icon="fa fa-edit" title="Editar" process="@this" update="dialogEmailForm" oncomplete="abrirJanela('adicionarEmail'); return false;" styleClass="btn btn-flat btn-default ui-button-grid">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{email}" target="#{clienteCadastroBean.clienteEmailSelecionado}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

Dialog:

```
<p:dialog header="Email" id="adicionarEmail" widgetVar="adicionarEmail" modal="true" resizable="false" closeOnEscape="true" draggable="false" styleClass="dialog-size-pequena" position="top" onShow="pageScroll('hide')" onHide="pageScroll('show')">   

        <div id="adicionarEmailConteudo" style="overflow-x: hidden;overflow-y: auto;">  
            <h:form id="dialogEmailForm">
                <p:messages autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <p:outputLabel value="Contato" for="contato" />
                        <p:inputText id="contato" value="#{clienteCadastroBean.clienteEmailSelecionado.contato}" maxlength="30" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <p:outputLabel value="E-mail" for="email" />
                        <p:inputText id="email" value="#{clienteCadastroBean.clienteEmailSelecionado.email}" maxlength="100" class="form-control minusculo" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <p:outputLabel value="Observação" for="observacao" />
                        <p:inputText id="observacao" value="#{clienteCadastroBean.clienteEmailSelecionado.observacao}" maxlength="50" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div align="right" style="padding-top: 20px">       
                    <p:commandButton actionListener="#{clienteCadastroBean.salvarEmail()}" class="btn btn-success" value="Salvar" 
                        update=":formClienteCadastro:emailGrid :dialogEmailForm" />
                    <p:spacer height="5" /> 
                    <p:commandButton process="@this" class="btn btn-default" value="Fechar" 
                        oncomplete="fecharJanela('adicionarEmail'); return false;" />
                </div>
            </h:form>
        </div>

</p:dialog>
```

Metodo salvar:

```
public void salvarEmail() {
    if (clienteEmailSelecionado.getId() == null) {  
        Long tamanhoLista = cliente.getClienteEmails().stream().filter(e -> clienteEmailSelecionado.getEmail().equals(e.getEmail())).count(); 
        verificaExistente(tamanhoLista);
        if (cliente.getId() != null) {
            ClienteEmail clienteEmailSavad = clienteEmailService.salvar(clienteEmailSelecionado);
            cliente.getClienteEmails().add(clienteEmailSavad);
        } else {
            cliente.getClienteEmails().add(clienteEmailSelecionado);
        }   
    } else {
        Long tamanhoLista = cliente.getClienteEmails().stream().filter(e -> clienteEmailSelecionado.getEmail().equals(e.getEmail())).filter(e -> !clienteEmailSelecionado.equals(e)).count();
        verificaExistente(tamanhoLista);               
        if (cliente.getId() != null) {
            clienteEmailService.salvar(clienteEmailSelecionado);
        }            
    }
    closeDialog("adicionarEmail");   
}
private void verificaExistente(Long tamanhoLista) {
    if (tamanhoLista > 0) {
        throw new TaskDoValidateException("Este endereço de e-mail já está cadastrado.");
    }    
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando eu vou editar um registro, e informo um email que já existe quando eu clico em salvar ele da o aviso na tela, e atualiza o registro já.

Answer (score 0):

Tente fazer dessa forma:

```
public void salvarEmail() {
    if (clienteEmailSelecionado.getId() == null) {  
        Long tamanhoLista = cliente.getClienteEmails().stream().filter(e -> clienteEmailSelecionado.getEmail().equals(e.getEmail())).count(); 
        if(verificaExistente(tamanhoLista)) {
            throw new TaskDoValidateException("Este endereço de e-mail já está cadastrado.");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            if (cliente.getId() != null) {
                ClienteEmail clienteEmailSavad = clienteEmailService.salvar(clienteEmailSelecionado);
                cliente.getClienteEmails().add(clienteEmailSavad);
            } else {
                cliente.getClienteEmails().add(clienteEmailSelecionado);
            }
        }
        return;
    } else {
        Long tamanhoLista = cliente.getClienteEmails().stream().filter(e -> clienteEmailSelecionado.getEmail().equals(e.getEmail())).filter(e -> !clienteEmailSelecionado.equals(e)).count();
        if(verificaExistente(tamanhoLista)) {
            throw new TaskDoValidateException("Este endereço de e-mail já está cadastrado.");
            return;
        }
        else
        {               
            if (cliente.getId() != null) {
                clienteEmailService.salvar(clienteEmailSelecionado);
            }       
        } 

        return;    
    }
    closeDialog("adicionarEmail");   
}

private bool verificaExistente(Long tamanhoLista) {
    if (tamanhoLista > 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: aconteceu a mesma coisa